# Try to convert xlsx file to html and then to pdf file but got errors NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I try to convert xlsx file to html table and then to convert the html to pdf. 
I do this because it is the only way for convert xlsx to pdf.

I use sheetJS and wkhtmltopdf package.

This is my code:

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');

router.get('/xlsx', async (request,  response) => {
    var xlsFile = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/temp/excel.xlsx');
    var html = XLSX.read(xlsFile, { type:'buffer' });
    const finalFile = XLSX.write(html, { type: 'binary', bookType: 'html' });
    wkhtmltopdf(finalFile, {
        output: './uplods/temp/xlsx.pdf',
        'viewport-size': '1280x1024',
        'page-width': '400',
        'page-height': '600'
    });
});
```

Error:

```
events.js:298
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:92:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:128:12)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:463:3)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:484:7)
    at internal/streams/destroy.js:60:7
    at Socket._destroy (net.js:677:5)
    at Socket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:55:8)
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:93:12) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Haven't used `wkhtmltopdf` but did notice you spelled it as `uplods/` versus `uploads` at the finalFile's path. Can you post to a github/bitbucket/jsfiddle?

Comment: I move to use libre office package it's convert all office files to pdf. you just need to install libre office on you machine/server in aws, etc... –

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine is having the same error using `wkhtmltopdf` however my system is running great.  I am on Linux with node version 13.9.0.

I used `npm search wkhtmltopdf` to see the version of my node module
node-wkhtmltopdf  2.0.0
wkhtmltopdf 0.3.4

The affected system is
os: mac os mojavi version: 10.14.6
node version: 13.8.0

What OS, package and node versions are you using?

---

update 2020-05-06
Our issues seemed in part due to AWS Lambda forcing a new version of node.
I now have it working in AWS with the following code:

```
return wkhtmltopdf(html)
    .then(buffer => {

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {

                'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'DAV, content-length, Allow'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"b64": buffer.toString('base64')}),
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        let msg = JSON.stringify({
            message: "s Internal server error ",
            error, html
        })
        return returnError(msg); 
    });
```

Comment: Hey I work with Catalina and last version of node. But I have new idea and I move to use libre office package it's convert all office files to pdf. you just need to install libre office on you machine/server in aws, etc...